# Verify WCF interface is the same between client and server applications

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

We've got a Windows service that is connected to various client applications via a duplex WCF channel.  The client and server applications are installed on different machines, in different locations, potentially at widely different times, and by different people.  In addition, the client can be pointed at a different machine running the same Windows service at startup.

Going forward, we know that the interface between the client and the server applications will likely evolve.  The application in the field will be administered by local IT personnel, and we have no real control over what version of either of these applications will be installed when/where or which will be connecting to the other. Since these are installed at various physical locations and by different people, there's a high likely that either the client or server application will be out of date compared to the other.

Since we can't control what versions of the applications in the field are trying to connect to each other, I'd like to be able to verify that the contracts between the client application and the server application are compatible.

Some things I'm looking for (may not be able to realistically get them all):

- I don't think I care if the server's interface is newer or older, as long as the server's interface is a super-set of the client's
- I want to use something other than an "interface version number".  Any developer-kept version number will eventually be forgotten about or missed.
- I'd like to use a computed interface comparison if that's possible

How can I do this?  Any ideas on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is a case of designing your service for versioning. WCF has very good versioning capabilities and extension points. Here are a couple of good MSDN articles on versioning the [service contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731060.aspx) and more specifically the [data contracts.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733832.aspx) For backward and "forward" compatible versioning look at this [article on using the IExtensibleDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731083.aspx) interface.

Comment: I've added the service contract information, but the problem I seem to be having at this point is actually catching a validation failure.  My channel just disconnects with no fault being thrown.  Any ideas?

Comment: You should start a new question describing your service and it's config. You should also describe how the client is created and what the client "disconnects" means. :)

Comment: I had figured that knowing when there was a problem with the contract was a required part of the interface verification I was looking for.  If I don't know when it fails, what's the point of the contract?  I have no problem posting a new question if that's what's needed, however, and can certainly do so to provide more information about the verification portion of the contract.

Answer (score 0):

If the server's endpoint has metadata publishing enabled, you can programmatically inspect an endpoint's interface by using the [MetadataResolver class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.metadataresolver.aspx). This class lets you retrieve the metadata from the server endpoint, and in your case, you would be interested in the ContractDescription which contains the list of all operations. You could then compare the list of operations to your [client proxy's endpoint operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms553831.aspx).

Of course now, comparing the lists of operations would need to be implemented, you could simply compare the operations names and fail if one of the client's operations is not found within the server's operations. This would not necessarily cover all incompatiblities, ex. request/response schema changes.

I have not tried implementing any of this by the way, so it's more of a theoretical view of your problem. If you don't want to fiddle with the framework, you could implement a custom operation that would return the list of operation names. This would be of minimal effort but is less standards-compliant.